# How do I define an array in C++ that holds GMP variables?

Tags: c++, gmp

How do I create an array in C++ that holds mpz variables?

I am trying to use:

```
int array_size = 5;
mpz_t numerator_arr;
for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
    mpz_init2(numerator_arr[i], 100);
}
numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };
```

but this returns the error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:34: error: cannot convert ‘__mpz_struct’ to ‘mpz_ptr {aka __mpz_struct*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void __gmpz_init2(mpz_ptr, mp_bitcnt_t)’
   mpz_init2(numerator_arr[i], 100);
                                  ^
test.cpp:17:38: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };
                                      ^
test.cpp:17:16: error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
  numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };
                ^
```

EDIT**: After some more digging, I found that I need to declare my array with

```
mpz_t *numerator_arr = new mpz_t[array_size];
```

but the compiler is still returning the errors:

```
test.cpp:17:38: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };
                                      ^
test.cpp:17:16: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘__mpz_struct (*)[1]’ in assignment
  numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };
                ^
```

When I try to use

```
vector<mpz_class> numerator_arr{ 1, -1, 1, -1, 5, -691, 7 };
```

it gives me the errors:

```
test.cpp:12:60: error: in C++98 ‘numerator_arr’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’
  vector<mpz_class> numerator_arr{ 1, -1, 1, -1, 5, -691, 7 };
                                                            ^
test.cpp:12:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
test.cpp:12:60: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/vector:64:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:398:9: note: template<class _InputIterator> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&)
         vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
         ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:398:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:60: note:   cannot convert ‘1’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘const allocator_type& {aka const std::allocator<__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> >&}’
  vector<mpz_class> numerator_arr{ 1, -1, 1, -1, 5, -691, 7 };
                                                            ^
```

When I try to use

```
mpz_class numerator_arr[] = { 1, -1, 1, -1 }
```

and I try to store numbers like

```
-94598037819122125295227433069493721872702841533066936133385696204311395415197247711
```

the compiler returns these warnings and errors:

```
test.cpp:29:3: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]
test.cpp:30:4: warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]
   -94598037819122125295227433069493721872702841533066936133385696204311395415197247711 };
    ^
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:30:88: error: conversion from ‘__int128 unsigned’ to ‘mpz_class {aka __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>}’ is ambiguous
   -94598037819122125295227433069493721872702841533066936133385696204311395415197247711 };
                                                                                        ^
test.cpp:30:88: note: candidates are:
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(double)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(float)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(long unsigned int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(long int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(short unsigned int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(short int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(unsigned int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(int)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(unsigned char)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1423:3: note: __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr(signed char)
   __GMPXX_DEFINE_ARITHMETIC_CONSTRUCTORS
   ^
```

This is my first time working with arrays in GMP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `numerator_arr = { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 };` only allowed when you are declaring `numerator_arr`

Comment: Did you `read` rupesh.yadav's comment before editing? Don't assign. Initialize!

Comment: Why not using a std::vector ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @ rupesh.yadav and harper
I believe I am initializing with the for loop.
@ Blacktempel
I require mpz because these numbers will get very large. What I have written is only a small sample of the numbers that I have.

Comment: AHHH. I think I see where this is going. So I need to use mpz_set_i for each element of my array? Is there no way to list the values like a normal c++ integer array? There is no pattern in the numbers of my array so using a for loop will not work and with the amount of numbers I have, doing this 1 at a time will get crazy...

Comment: You're probably better off using the C++ interface to GMP. You can write `std::vector<mpz_class> numerator_arr { 1, -1, 1, 5, -691 }` if I read the docs correctly.

Comment: I just gave that a try. It is giving me a whole bunch of errors. I have included the errors in my post.

Comment: The vector thing is C++11, you need to pass `-std=gnu++11` to g++ for it to work. Otherwise, you could use `mpz_class numerator_arr[]={1,-1,42};` even in old C++.

Comment: Hmm.. The array has trouble storing numbers like -94598037819122125295227433069493721872702841533066936133385696204311395415197247711

Comment: I am now storing the numbers that are too large to fit as strings instead of signed integers. Is there any convenient way to do arithmetic with these numbers as strings?

Comment: Instead of just typing 1234, you can write `mpz_class("1234")` (or `1234_mpz` for short if you have C++11). This accepts arbitrarily long numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, summing up all the comments above, if you are dealing with a lot of array modification in your code(insertion/remove) it is best to use `vector<mpz_class>` to hold your mpz_class variables.
And the reason that it is better for you to use `mpz_class` instead of `mpz_t` is first you don't have to worry about keeping track with memory you use for the variables(`mpz_init()/mpz_clear()`) and second the code you write becomes much clearer as many of operators are mapped with `mpz_class`

Regarding the errors, your `vector<mpz_class>` code is resulting error because you are not correctly instantiating the variables. May be what you meant was

```
mpz_class numerator_arr[] = { 1, -1, 1, -1 };
vector<mpz_class> arr (numerator_arr);
```

And when you tried to store huge numbers into a mpz_class you are getting an error because the when you initialize the mpz_class with like this:

```
mpz_class m(-11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
```

you are already initializing huge number into the primitive int type. And in your case the number is assigned as an unsigned 16 byte int because it is just too large and gmp does not provide any constructor to make it into its `mpz_class` structure.
You will be better of making the input argument as string(const char*) rather than an int. So it will be

```
mpz_class m("-11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
```

Hope this helps.